# Error when Installing NPM module during Meteor.js's MUP Deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, node-gyp, meteor-up

I'm deploying a Meteor v0.9.3 app from a OSX system onto an Ubuntu 14.04 system using Meteor-up `mup` v0.6.8. It gives an error as shown below.

Repeated `npm i -g mup`, `mup setup`, `mup deploy` but it didn't solve the problem.

Seems like there's a problem rebuilding the NPM packages. Has anyone encountered this issue before? Wonder if its `npm-container`?

```
$ mup deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

Bundling Started: .

Started TaskList: Deploy app 'my-test-app' (linux)
[192.168.1.114] - Uploading bundle
[192.168.1.114] ✔ Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[192.168.1.114] - Setting up Environment Variables
[192.168.1.114] ✔ Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[192.168.1.114] - Invoking deployment process
[192.168.1.114] ✘ Invoking deployment process: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/my-test-app/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-container/node_modules/serialport',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
    gyp: Undefined variable module_name in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
    gyp ERR! configure error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 3.12.28+
    gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /opt/my-test-app/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-container/node_modules/serialport
    gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.32
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    => re-installing binary npm module 'serialport' of package 'npm-container'
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Completed TaskList: Deploy app 'my-test-app' (linux)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I was having the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 and this solved it immediately.